# How to change a attribute conditionally be checking its sibling's value?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to change some attribute values only for some specific element.
For example, is it possible to change @lang only for the books whose price is 29.99 in below XML?

```
<book>
  <title lang="fr">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation (no explicit conditionals at all)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="book[price=29.99]/title/@lang">
  <xsl:attribute name="lang">ChangedLang</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML** (wrapped to a wellformed XML document):

```
<t>
    <book>
        <title lang="fr">Harry Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <book>
      <title lang="ChangedLang">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
      <price>39.95</price>
   </book>
</t>
```

**Explanation**: Overriding the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** for the desired attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

**XML Source**

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title lang="fr">Harry Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</books>
```

**Sample XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <books>
            <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </books>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="book">
            <book>
                <title>
                    <xsl:if test="price = '29.99'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="lang">eng</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                <price><xsl:value-of select="price"/></price>
            </book>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Alternative Template**

Or do you really want to use the following-sibling axes when matching the title node? If so this may be better:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <title>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::price[1] = '29.99'">
            <xsl:attribute name="lang">eng</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </title>
</xsl:template>
```